# Does $HK = H'K$ imply $H \cong H'$ in this context?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a group and $p\in\mathbb{N}$. Suppose there exists $g\in G$ of infinite order (*i.e.* $\langle g\rangle :\!= \{g^n:n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ is infinite) which commutes with all elements of $G$.

I will say that a normal subgroup $H \trianglelefteq G$ is a *$p$-complement* of $g$ if $\langle g\rangle H :\!= \{g^nh: h\in H, n\in \mathbb{Z}\} = G$, $\langle g\rangle \cap H = \langle g^p\rangle$ and $H/\langle g^n\rangle$ is finite.

My question is: are any two $p$-complements of $g$ isomorphic?

My intuition says that they should be isomorphic. Indeed, if $H,H'$ are $p$-complements of $g$, then from the isomorphisms theorems we have $H/\langle g^n\rangle \cong G/\langle g\rangle \cong H'/\langle g^n\rangle$.
Moreover, the theorem below gives an affirmative answer in a similar context.

**Theorem.** Let $K$ be a finite group. Suppose that $K = LM = LM'$, where $L,M,M'$ are normal groups in $G$ satisfying $L\cap M = L\cap M' = \{1\}$. Then, $L\cong L'$.

Any comment is appreciated.

Comment: The notation $G'$ in group theory typically means "the derived subgroup of $G$".

Comment: What is $n$ in $H/\langle g^n\rangle$?

Comment: @Shaun You tend to meet such entities well after these initial basics about normal groups and subset products have been tidied up and put out of the way. While it may be prudent to use something like $H$ and $K$ rather than $H$ and $H'$, it will rarely cause any confusion to use $H'$ in this specific context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Let $G=\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/2$ and $p=2$.
- Let $g=(1,0)$.
- Let $H=\langle (0,1),(2,0)\rangle$ and $K=\langle (1,1)\rangle$.  In this case, $H=\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/2$ and $K=\mathbb{Z}$.

Since the group is Abelian, $g$ commutes with everything and is of infinite order.  In both cases, $\langle g\rangle H=G=\langle g\rangle K$; in fact, they are index-$2$ subgroups.  Also, $H\cap\langle g\rangle=\langle (2,0)\rangle=K\cap\langle g\rangle$.  Finally, the quotients $H/\langle (2,0)\rangle$ and $K/\langle (2,0)\rangle$ are finite since they are index-$2$ subgroups of $H$ and $K$.

Pictorially, I view $G$ as two infinite sequences of dots along two parallel lines.  Then $K$ consists of a sequence of dots alternating between the two parallel lines (left-right-left-right) while $H$ consists of alternating pairs of dots (two-foot jumping)